# How to use typescript generics constraints with useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, constraints, typescript-generics

I am learning Typescript and have a custom React hook similar to this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

type TypeOne = {
  one: string;
};
type TypeTwo = {
  two: number;
};
type TypeThree = {
  three: {
    some: string;
  };
}
type AnyPropertyWithString = {
  [index: string]: string | AnyPropertyWithString;
};

export function getContent(condition: string): Promise<AnyPropertyWithString> {
  return Promise.resolve({ one: 'content' });
}

export default function useContent<T extends AnyPropertyWithString>(
  initial: T,
  condition: string
): T {
  const [content, setContent] = useState<T>(initial);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const data = await getContent(condition);
      setContent(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [condition]);

  return content;
}
```

My intention is to provide different types of data to this hook initially and save it in a state. Then fetch new data on some condition and replace the state. I want to restrict the type provided to the hook to `AnyPropertyWithString`. I want to use generic because the types I will provide could have different properties and multiple levels. The return type should be the same as generic.

I expect to use it like this:

```
const one: TypeOne = { one: 'content' };
const two: TypeTwo = { two: 2 };
const three: TypeThree = { three: { some: '3' } }

const firstResult = useContent(one, 'condition'); // ok
const secondResult = useContent(two, 'condition'); // expected TS error
const thirdResult = useContent(three, 'condition'); // ok
```

However, when I try to `setContent(data)`, I have an error:

```
Argument of type 'AnyPropertyWithString' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<T>'.
  Type 'AnyPropertyWithString' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'AnyPropertyWithString' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'AnyPropertyWithString'.
```

I don't want to cast it to `T` as I've read that this is a bad practice.

I suspect the problem is that `getContent` returns the data of the type that can't be effectively matched against, but I thought that generic constraint would narrow down T to `AnyPropertyWithString` (which is returned by `getContent`).
I tried `useState<T | AnyPropertyWithString>`, but then I have a problem with the return type. I also tried different combinations of `extends`, but none worked.

Could you, please, explain why I have this error and how I can work around it if that's possible?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

How is `getContent` supposed to know what `T` is, and then return data in the format of `T`?

When you do this:

```
const hookReturnValue = useContent({ foo: string }, 'condition')
```

Then the `T` type in `useContent` is `{ foo: string }`, which is a subtype of `AnyPropertyWithString`. `getContent` returns an entirely different subtype of `T`.

So if this code ran, then the initial value would set `T` to `{ foo: string }`, then the effect would run and you would save `{ one: string }` to state, which is not a compatible type.

Then your code would do:

```
const hookReturnValue = useContent({ foo: string }, 'condition')
hookReturnValue.foo.toUpperCase() // crash when effect completes
```

This is what is meant by this error:

> 'AnyPropertyWithString' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'AnyPropertyWithString'.

---

It's unclear how `getContent` would work, but it would need to know what kind of data format to return at runtime, and you aren't passing it anything that would let it figure that out.

So if you figure out how `getContent` will return the same type as the `initial` argument type of the hook, then the answer will start reveal itself.